# Quiero incluir este texto en mi código Genexus

Tags: genexus15

Como incluyo esta línea de comando en Genexus

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=Client_Truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Donde está el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].